# adjust line spacing of entries using tocloft

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

When using `tocloft` in a `book` class document with chapter and section entries, the line spacing within chapter entries should be adjustable, but how? As it stands the section entries in the ToC are set with `\cftbeforesecskip` to `-0.3em`. However, when some of the chapter entries take up more than one line the resulting line spacing within chapter entries is wider than between chapter and section entries. How to adjust line spacing for chapter entries in ToC so that they are the same as the spacing between chapter and section entries?

MwE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{-0.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small\normalfont}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A short chapter heading}
\section{A section header}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{A much longer chapter heading that with a narrower page size streches overmultiple lines in the ToC}
\section{A section header}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want all your ToC entries to be `\small` then try:

```
%\documentclass...
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\small} % ToC in small font
% body of document
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if you just eliminate your `\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{-0.3em}` then the spacing is constant. Why do you want to squish the section entries? It looks ugly to me.